# Not accepting the crypt disk password at boot to unlock the disk for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, password, cryptsetup

This is really a major issue. Check what happened. Please Help me with a solution...

I had windows 7 installed in my laptop. I decided to install ubuntu 14.04 and remove windows 7. So while installing ubuntu 14.04 i selected remove windows 7 and install ubuntu (2nd option).
I selected cryptdisk option while installing and set a password.

Later after installation i couldn't find my old partition and data. So I tried to check the partition and other settings. During this I shutdown my system and started again. **(Remember never clicked restart instead used shutdown)**

After a research i found testdisk software which can help for recovering partitions. I did it and found my partition and i selected to write the MBR to disk. After this testdisk asked me to restart to take effect. 
So I restarted the system **(Notice this time i clicked restart icon)**. After this when the system restarted I entered the same cryptdisk password at ubuntu boot screen. but it didnt except and gave error: **"requested offset is beyond real size of device ...." cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?"**

Please someone help me with this... Waiting for a good response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this post and it looks similar and the person has the same size error http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/recover-from-deleted-luks-encryption-partition-4175435883/

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 and only using lowercase letters and a shorter password. There is most certainly a bug in this software.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I removed a fair bit of your answer because it was  not relevant to understanding the solution. I also removed an issue you were experiencing. Please [Ask a question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) regarding any other issues.

Comment: No, there is most likely a different keyboard layout set at boot.